# WCF is blocked when using HTTPS

Tags: web-services, wcf, https, web-config, xmlhttprequest

We recently went from HTTP to HTTPS and our web-services stopped working and I've been trying several approaches to get them to work again.

It seems to me that they are up and running but all calls to them gets blocked for some reason...

The error I'm getting

```
Mixed Content: The page X at 'https://website/project/page.aspx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://website:123/WebService/ProjectTreeService.svc/Clone'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

My web.config file is set up like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ProjectTreeService_webHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="PROJ.IProjectTreeService" behaviorConfiguration="ProjectTreeService_ServiceBehaviour"> 
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProjectTreeService_webHttpBinding" contract="PROJ.IProjectTreeService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ProjectTreeService_ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Any ideas what I've missed?

EDIT:

I don't know if it any help but when I browse(https://website:123/WebService/ProjectTreeService.svc) to the service I can see that the set_path function goes with http

```
 PROJ.Service.Internal.IProjectTreeService.set_path("http://website:123/WebService/ProjectTreeService.svc");
```

Comment: You simply cannot call an http based service from within a page that you deliver via https. That is indeed blocked by browsers for security reasons.

Comment: huh.. I didn't know that. So what can I do to make this work? A lot of functionality is depending on internally using the web services within the page.

Comment: Certainly you can use your web services in background! What you cannot do is use them with the unencrypted http protocol from within a page loaded with the encrypted https protocol. But that is what you are trying to do, according to what you posted. The reason why this is blocked by browsers is obvious: the user trusts in your page using encryption. He cannot see that background communication (probably ajax requests?). So he cannot see that _this_ communication is _not_ encrypted! So the answer here is: you have to use https for _both_, the page _and_ those web services.

Comment: Alright so How do I have my internal web service calls do it over https instead of http? I thought that's what the web.config did..

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know what `wcf` is, I only mentioned the above because it is a general issue designed by purpose with good reasons. So I am afraid i cannot help here. But one thing looks odd to me in your code above: `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>`. Looks like you enable _both_?

Comment: Ah yes, I've been fiddling around with the settings a bit so forgot to change httpGetEnabled to false. Perhaps I should try to enable both http and https connections to see if that would solve it.